# How to play external video file using Firemonkey?

Tags: delphi, video, firemonkey

How to play an external file ie. http://mycompany.com/myfile.mp4
on Delphi Seattle firemonkey for both IOS and Android?

As far as i can see `TMediaPlayer` is for local files only.
proper way to have smouth video playback?

thank you.

Comment: Firemonkey's WebBrowser does not support the html <video> tag nor it can load that kind of files and show the video. You may look for a 3rd party component but I'd suggest you to use a something similar to TWebBrowser

Comment: Or better, download the file and play it with TMediaPlayer!

Comment: It depends, are you looking to stream it in real-time? Or is it okay to have a delay of downloading?

Comment: its for a movie player and i dont undertsand a product like delphi of 5.000++ euros and they havent done a component to play an external mp4 yet? !!!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to play external file is to use DASH or HLS. Also if you want to fully integrate the playing inside Firemonkey, ie not put a player windows on the top of your firemonkey windows, but play the video INSIDE your firemonkey windows then take a look at  https://github.com/Zeus64/alcinoe (support also DASH and HLS)